# using constant seed at pseudorandomgenerator getting not the same numbers from UT and GUI

Tags: c++, boost, random

I defined a constant seed on the pseudo number generator and obviously i should get always the same numbers. However running the same code over GUI and UT I am not getting the same number sequences. What could be the possible problem?

I am running it on Windows 7, VS2012, using C++10x, using this boost library as shown below.

```
typedef boost::mt19937_64 base_generator_type;
typedef boost::variate_generator<base_generator_type&,   
            boost::normal_distribution<double> > NormalDistribution;
base_generator_type engine(2);
boost::normal_distribution<double> norm_dist(mean, variance);
NormalDistribution normDistribution(engine, norm_dist);
number=normDistribution();
```

I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: What is `UT`? Is `GUI` Graphical User Interface or something else?

Comment: Please don't use not-so-popular abbreviation in the question.

Comment: `C++10x` is a typo, right?

Comment: Are you running both tests on the same machine? The differences may stem from differences in the FPU. (While I'm of course aware why you want to, getting reproducable results with floating point numbers is always a bit tricky.)

Comment: If you are running both on the same platform and environment you should get the same sequence of numbers, for what I know. Are you sure you are checking the generated number sequence correctly? In a GUI application there might be quite a few calls to event functions that possibly also use your pseudo random number generator and which interfere with the numbers what you are recording. So first, I would put a loop of ten iterations right behind the creation of your generator and do the first ten numbers before any event function is called and compare these to the non-GUI run.

Answer (score 0):

@nv3 already hinted at my suspicion.

The code, as shown, does not explain the difference, but if more callers consume the same  base generator then these will interfere.

The typedef

```
typedef boost::variate_generator<base_generator_type&, 
    boost::normal_distribution<double> > NormalDistribution;
```

specifically invites this by taking the base generator by reference. This makes it all the more easy to end up with several distributions referring to the same base generator.

See e.g. this simple example:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/036c8c56e8e6c5ca)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/math/distributions/normal.hpp>
#include <algorithm>

typedef boost::mt19937_64 base_generator_type;
typedef boost::variate_generator<base_generator_type&, boost::normal_distribution<double> > NormalDistribution;

int main() {
    base_generator_type engine(2);
    double mean = 10, variance = 1;

    {
        boost::normal_distribution<double> norm_dist(mean, variance);
        NormalDistribution normDistribution(engine, norm_dist);

        std::generate_n(std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, "; "), 10, normDistribution);
    }

    std::cout << "\nrepeat\n";

    {
        boost::normal_distribution<double> norm_dist(mean, variance);
        NormalDistribution normDistribution(engine, norm_dist);

        std::generate_n(std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, "; "), 10, normDistribution);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
8.26665; 11.5482; 11.8322; 12.0042; 9.65992; 10.1167; 10.4089; 10.0795; 9.98147; 9.28229; 
repeat
8.48879; 9.80004; 9.6922; 9.87253; 10.3786; 10.4362; 10.0724; 10.1243; 9.0849; 10.8096;
```

Clearly, the repeat isn't identical _because some other party has consumed random numbers from `engine`.

Now, just isolating the engines by removing the `&` in that typedef:

```
typedef boost::variate_generator<base_generator_type,
      boost::normal_distribution<double> > NormalDistribution;
```

makes it repeat ok:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02f3d6469acb4472)</kbd>**

```
8.26665; 11.5482; 11.8322; 12.0042; 9.65992; 10.1167; 10.4089; 10.0795; 9.98147; 9.28229; 
repeat
8.26665; 11.5482; 11.8322; 12.0042; 9.65992; 10.1167; 10.4089; 10.0795; 9.98147; 9.28229;
```

So you might try this, or otherwise make sure other components (related to the GUI) do not share the `base_generator_type` object.